# I am unable to connect to rasa server using html

Tags: error-handling, server, chatbot, rasa

I am trying to connect to rasa server hosted on one centos vm and its html file hosted in another vm which has apache server.

When I have tried the chatbot widget pops up and no errors in console but, the rasa server vm is showing this error:
**[ERROR] Exception occurred while handling uri: 'ws://di2inpu:5005/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=o6THi_XXleVLyledAAAE'**

So I have tried opening the rasa server web page i.e di2inpu:5005 and it was showing "Hello from rasa 3.X.X".

This are the details of rasa version:
[rasa version details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYWPc.png)

This is my html file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jZ4n.png)

I have tried from different machines and by changing the ports but did not work.
I am expecting an alternate approach which can solve this problem

Comment: please add the code as text to your question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors